# Socket ObjectOutputStream writeUTF() and ObjectInputStream readUTF() not working

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I was trying to do a chat and I notice that `readUTF()` and `writeUTF()` did not work. `readUTF()` stays waiting when I already used `writeUTF()`. I made a simple test and does not work, what I am doing bad?

(I know that I could use Data Streams instead of Object Streams but in my chat I want to write objects and strings)

Server code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(40001);

        Socket s = server.accept();
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

        System.out.println(in.readUTF());
        out.writeUTF("E");
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 40001);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

        out.writeUTF("A");
        System.out.println(in.readUTF());
    }
}
```

I could use `writeObject("A")` and cast the String with `readObject()`, but I want to know why this way does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `flush()` after writing using `writeUTF`. The reason that `writeObject` just seems to work is that `writeObject` will switch to a specific mode before it starts writing, and switch back after it is done. This switching back will automatically flush the buffered data (at least in Java 11). This is not the case for `writeUTF`, and an explicit call to `flush()` is needed.

Comment: Do I need to flush every time I write or I can do multiple writes and then flush?

Comment: @NapoZ You only need to flush when you want to be sure the data is sent to the other side of the connection. So, you can do multiple writes and then flush.